# How to force postgres to return 0 even if there are no rows matching query, using coalesce, group by and join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, coalesce

I've been trying hopelessly to get the following SQL statement to return the query results and default to 0 if there are no rows matching the query.

This is the intended result:

```
  vol  | year 
-------+------
   0   | 2018
```

Instead I get:

```
 vol | year 
-----+------
(0 rows)
```

Here is the sql statement:

```
select coalesce(vol,0) as vol, year
from (select sum(vol) as vol, year
      from schema.fact_data
         join schema.period_data
            on schema.fact_data.period_tag = schema.period_data.tag 
         join schema.product_data
            on schema.fact_data.product_tag = 
schema.product_data.tag
         join schema.market_data
            on schema.fact_data.market_tag = schema.market_data.tag
      where "retailer"='MadeUpRetailer'
        and "product_tag"='FakeProductTag'
        and "year"='2018' group by year
     ) as DerivedTable;
```

I know the query works because it returns data when there is data. Just doesn't default to 0 as intended...

Any help in finding why this is the case would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please qualify all your column names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your subquery `DerivedTable`, you could write:

```
SELECT coalesce(DerivedTable.vol, 0) AS vol,
       y.year
FROM (VALUES ('2018'::text)) AS y(year)
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT ...) AS DerivedTable
      ON DerivedTable.year = y.year;
```

Comment: But this will work only for year 2018. Correct? I think 2018 was an example.

Comment: Well, there was `2018` in the query in the question. It is no problem to use a parameter in this place.

Comment: @Neptune: If you want to do this for a range of years (say, from `2000` to `2018`), then replace `VALUES ('2018'::text)` with `SELECT generate_series(2000, 2018)::text`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks for your answer! I can't get this snippet to work, what exactly would you replace ... by from my example?

Comment: If you replace the `...` in my query with your subquery, you get the desired result, right? If no, please tell me the error (I didn't test it). If yes, please explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: This is the error I am getting: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "y"
LINE 2:        y.year`

Comment: Zounds! I forgot a comma at the end of the first line. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `GROUP BY` (and the outer query):

```
select 2018 as year, coalesce(sum(vol), 0) as vol
from schema.fact_data f join
     schema.period_data p
     on f.period_tag = p.tag join
     schema.product_data pr
     on f.product_tag = pr.tag join
     schema.market_data m
     on fd.market_tag = m.tag
where "retailer" = 'MadeUpRetailer' and
      "product_tag" = 'FakeProductTag' and
      "year" = '2018';
```

An aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` always returns exactly one row, so this should do what you want.

EDIT:

The query would look something like this:

```
select v.yyyy as year, coalesce(sum(vol), 0) as vol
from (values (2018), (2019)) v(yyyy) left join
     schema.fact_data f
     on f.year = v.yyyy left join  -- this is just an example.  I have no idea where year is coming from
     schema.period_data p
     on f.period_tag = p.tag left join
     schema.product_data pr
     on f.product_tag = pr.tag left join
     schema.market_data m
     on fd.market_tag = m.tag
group by v.yyyy
```

However, you have to move the `where` conditions to the appropriate `on` clauses.  I have no idea where the columns are coming from.

Comment: This query does indeed return one row, but then the 2018 column is still empty which is not the desired behaviour

Comment: @ludo . . . If you want `0` instead of `NULL`, just use `coalesce()`.

Comment: Thanks for this @GordonLinoff. I get the desired result! However, I need the results to be grouped by the year. So if I put `where year in (2018,2019)` then the query would group on the year and return two rows regardless of whether the rows have data or not. Do you have any idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted it is not clear in which table you have the `year` column. 
You can use UNION to fetch just 1 row in case there are no rows in that table for the year 2018 like this:

```
select sum(vol) as vol, year
from schema.fact_data innrt join schema.period_data
on schema.fact_data.period_tag = schema.period_data.tag 
inner join schema.product_data
on schema.fact_data.product_tag = schema.product_data.tag
inner join schema.market_data
on schema.fact_data.market_tag = schema.market_data.tag
where 
  "retailer"='MadeUpRetailer' and 
  "product_tag"='FakeProductTag' and 
  "year"='2018'
group by "year"
union 
select 0 as vol, '2018' as year
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename where "year" = '2018' 
)
```

In case there are rows for the year 2018, then nothing will be fetched by the 2nd query,